# Passing custom variables via paypal (IPN) gives me wrong values

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to figure this out alone. However, there is something odd going on here. I've got a hidden custom field with the e-mail of a user (just in case they use another email at paypal), but - when the IPN request is done, the custom field is strong my IP address? is there any reason for this?

Form,

```
    <input name="description" id="description" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $paypal_product ?>" />
    <input name="amount" id="amount" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $paypal_price ?>"   />
    <input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $paypal_product_id ?>"   />
    <input name="currency" id="currency" type="hidden" value="NOK"   />
    <input name="custom" id="custom" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('mail') ?>, <?php echo $paypal_product_id ?>"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

From a PayPal point of view there's no reason for this. It simply means $this->session->userdata('mail') doesn't contain what you expect it to. Debug, echo, debug.

Comment: Ok, why would't paypal understand the email given by a session in the hidden view? It's sent before the payment is even started, just so i can pick it up when the IPN call returns back to me, for future validation etc. Please explain!

Comment: Sorry? Can you please clarify what you mean? PayPal doesn't touch the values of the custom field at all. If you're getting an IP address returned in the IPN message, it simply means you initially sent it as such to PayPal in the first place.